# A simple congruence problem

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $x,y,z$ be three non-zero positive integers. If $y>x$ and $y^z \equiv 0 \pmod x$, does it imply $y \equiv 0 \pmod x$? How do I prove it? I know this may be obvious for most of you.  I just need some guidance.Thanks.

Comment: The implication does not hold. For example, let $x=4$, $y=6$, and $z=2$.

Comment: Correct. Thank you very much.

Comment: You are welcome. The desired result will hold if, for example, $x$ is not divisible by any square greater than $1$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, would you please explain? Do you mean $x$ must be prime?

Comment: Not necessarily prime. For example $x=2\cdot 3\cdot 5$ would be OK, any product of possibly many **distinct** primes.

Comment: so what do you mean? an example please.

Comment: There is an example above. If $y^z\equiv 0\pmod{30}$, then $y\equiv 0\pmod{30}$.

Answer (score 3):

Not necessarily no, $4\mid 6^2$, but $4\nmid 6$.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach was of a greater aspect which states that p must be a prime.

If it is so,

Then

$y^z$ contains only $y$ and if $x|y$ then $x|{y^z}$.

So $x$ does not contain any other factor but 1 and itself.

So we go on to see that if ,

${y^z}\equiv0(mod x)$

Then $x|{y^z}$

Then the prime factor representation of $y^z$ contains only $y$ and when $x|{y^z}$ , the prime $x$ must appear in the representation of $y^z$ which contains nothing more but $z$ numbers of $y$ so the prime $x$ must be present in $y$

Hence $x|y$

$\Rightarrow y\equiv0(mod x)$